# Create a grey box background within an Ax 2009 report

Tags: report, dynamics-ax-2009

I always seem to be having fun working with the Ax 2009 product until I have to touch the now deprecated reporting tool.  Today I've been asked to highlight some column titles and a totals area with a grey or shaded background.  The *tutorial_ColourLines* report isn't what I need as we do not want to [colour the whole report section](http://dynamics-ax-live.blogspot.com/2009/12/use-colors-in-report.html).  We only want to [change the background color for labels](http://dynamicsuser.net/forums/p/43202/218771.aspx) or better yet, inside a shape.

Thanks

Comment: I couldn't get this trick for the changing the background colour for a text area to work: Link in Spanish - http://www.trucosax.com/phpnuke/modules.php?name=Forums&file=viewtopic&t=1193&highlight=&NSNST_Flood=782a1a8949451972d2721aad42c3de52

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Revisiting the TrucosAx.com link in Spanish I posted in the questions comments, I've obtained an imperfect way of producing the silver backgrounds.

- Create a Text object but makes sure it is behind all of the other controls, by moving it up the list of objects in the report section.
- Set the new object as having the same dimensions and position as our original column title or label.
- Change the original column title background colour.
- Change the foreground and background colour of our new text object as well.
- Fill the text object's Text property with garbage: OOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO etc.

Any better suggestion is most welcome.